# Quadratic Equation with 2 Variables

Tags: quadratics

I have this Equation :
$xy + y^2 = 19 + 2x^2$

I need to find every $(x , y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

I first tried to solve it by dividing everything by $y^2$ , but $19$ creates a problem , because we will get term $19/y^2$ , which is cumbersome & may or may not be Integer.

I next tried to solve for $x$ and check when is square root of Discriminant integer, but not sure how to check that.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far as part of the question? It will help people to give you more useful answers.

Comment: @ChrisLewis i already said what i tried.

Comment: @NikoMolecule you said that one approach "creates a problem" and another you're "not sure" about. What problem? What aren't you sure about?

Comment: This is the equation of a [conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section). You can reduce it to standard form by a change of variables.

Comment: Hint: you want to use the fact $x$ and $y$ are integers. Both your approaches ignore this - you're looking at solving for reals. Can you see a way to rearrange and factorise the equation?

Comment: @ChrisLewis I will try it and tell you soon

Comment: @ChrisLewis i factorised equation to this:

$$(y + \sqrt{19})(y - \sqrt{19}) = x(2x - y)$$

Comment: @NikoMolecule See the answer by Prem for the factorisation. In your comment, again, you avoided the fact that $x$ and $y$ are integers. The point is, you know everything there is to know about integer factors of $19$, so the fact you're after integer solutions is more "important" than the fact it's a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Diophantine Equation , involving Quadratic terms.

Let us take the given Equation :
$xy+y^2=19+2x^2\tag{1}$

Move the terms around , to get :
$xy+y^2-2x^2=19$
$xy-x^2+y^2-x^2=19$

We can now factorize this :
$x(y-x)+(y+x)(y-x)=19$
$[x+y+x](y-x)=19\tag{2}$

We have 2 Integers , which give Prime Number $19$ when multiplied.
Hence , the Numbers must be either $\pm 1$ or $\pm 19$.
$[x+y+x]=+19 \land (y-x)=+1\tag{3}$
$[x+y+x]=+1 \land (y-x)=+19\tag{4}$
$[x+y+x]=-19 \land (y-x)=-1\tag{5}$
$[x+y+x]=-1 \land (y-x)=-19\tag{6}$

Solve these <strike>two</strike> four Sets of Equations to get the Solutions , selecting Integer Solutions.

With (3) & (4) , We will get Solutions $(6,7)$ & $(-6,13)$ which are Integers.

With (5) & (6) , User TonyK gives the Solutions $(-6,-7)$ & $(6,-13)$ which are Integers too.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpfull <3

Comment: You mean, the numbers must be $\pm 1$ or $\pm 19$. This gives the additional solutions $(-6,-7)$ and $(6,-13)$.

Comment: Oh yes , I missed those $\pm$ Cases , @TonyK , thank you ! I will add those Cases now !